# Close Persistent Material UI Drawer on clicking outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use `Drawer component` in Material UI React. I want that state inside the `Drawer component` should not lost on closing of Drawer component, hence I'm passing `variant="persistent"` in Drawer component.

Now, the problem is that the `Persistent Drawer` does not provide `backdrop functionality` by default unlike `temporary` drawers hence I'm unable to close it on outside click.
I tried `{{ModalProps={{ onBackdropClick: this.toggleDrawer }} }}` also but still it is not working.

Is there any workaround for this?

**Material UI Version: 1.0.0**

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/50rz01oxz4)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `ClickAwayListener` component for this.
https://material-ui.com/api/click-away-listener/

```
import ClickAwayListener from '@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener';

const drawer = (
      <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.handleDrawerClose}>
        <Drawer
          variant="persistent"
          anchor={anchor}
          open={open}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
            <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
              {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
                <ChevronRightIcon />
              ) : (
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              )}
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <Divider />
          <List>a asdasd</List>
          <Divider />
          <List>asdasd</List>
        </Drawer>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/072ny1rjw

Comment: There is something weird with this. I was trying to do the same thing and had to google because it was confusing me. The `onClickedAway` is called every time clicking somewhere else, also when the drawer is not open (so it is still rendered, when not open?) anyway. this result in some behaviour where the open/close function are fighting, and when I click my open button the close function is also called from the ClickAwayListener.

Comment: This works well unless your button to trigger the drawer is outside of the `ClickAwayListener`. In that case, you need to add logic to the `onClickAway` function to check if the `ShowDrawerButton` was just clicked and then not fire the action of the `ClickAwayListener`.

Comment: Yes for example, we can put the ClickAwayListener component around the AppBar. 
To display the drawer, we click on the menu icon in the AppBar. So there will be no problem to display the drawer or hide it.

Comment: This answer should be removed. It doesn't work, and Drawer has this functionality out of the box via `onClose`/`onBackdropClick`

Comment: @ Liran H`onClose/onBackdropClick` does not work with  variant="persistent"

Comment: This answer did not work for me. Please update the answer to add a warning based on these comments.

Comment: One trick to using `ClickAwayListener` in this kind of scenario is to **not** render the `ClickAwayListener` at all if `open` variable is not `true`. So something like: `{open && <ClickAwayListener>...</ClickAwayListener>}`. That way it only intercepts outside clicks when the drawer is showing.

Comment: @RasmusPuls inf your case, the way you can overcome this is to remove the listener for onClickedAway when the drawer is not opened. My solution was the following :
`<ClickAwayListener mouseEvent={open ? "onClick" : false}>...</ClickAwayListener>}`

Answer (score 36):

For the sake of searchers landing on this question. If you are having trouble with `ClickAwayListener` and are not using `variant='persistent'`. Try this instead: Providing a toggle function to `ModalProps` `onBackdropClick`

```
<Drawer
  open={drawerIsOpen}
  ModalProps={{ onBackdropClick: this.toggleDrawer }}
>
  <MenuItem>drawer item 1</MenuItem>
</Drawer>
```

**UPDATE July 2021:**

I recently updated `material-ui/core` to version `4.12.1` and noticed that `onBackdropClick` is being deprecated. Instead they have added native support for this functionality, the `onClose` function will be called automatically when clicking outside the drawer, and it now gives a `reason` for why it was called:

Signature:
`function(event: object, reason: string) => void`

`event`: The event source of the callback.

`reason`: Can be: "escapeKeyDown", "backdropClick"

See example here: https://material-ui.com/api/modal/ scroll down to onBackDropClicked - it works the same for the drawer as it does for the

Do this instead:

```
<Drawer
  open={drawerIsOpen}
  onClose={{ (ev, reason) => this.setState({ drawerIsOpen: false }) }}
>
  <MenuItem>drawer item 1</MenuItem>
</Drawer>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. ClickAwayListener didnt work for me either as it was triggering the moment I tried to open the drawer, hence blocked the toggle opening. This fixed the issue and I personally think its more elegant than the accepted answer

Comment: This only worked because you ignored the `variant="persistent"` constraint that removes the backdrop... it's written in the question.

Comment: The ClickAwayListener didn't work for me when using `variant="temporary"`. This solution worked nicely.

Answer (score 17):

I spend some time training to fix this, but I found a really a useful solution and is to change the variant to Temporary and use de onEscapeKeyDown and the onBackdropClick as follow:

```
  <Drawer
    variant="temporary"
    onEscapeKeyDown={handleDrawerClose}
    onBackdropClick={handleDrawerClose}
    open={open}
    ...rest of your code...
```

Comment: Done with ease. Thanks a lot for this super useful solution.

Answer (score 10):

Working solution in **MUI v5**:

#### Persistent `Drawer`

Use `ClickAwayListener` to know when the user clicks outside the `Drawer`. You also need to set `mouseEvent="onMouseDown"`, otherwise the `onClickAway` callback is fired after the user clicks the open button and make the `Drawer` close immediately before it can be opened.

```
<ClickAwayListener
  mouseEvent="onMouseDown"
  touchEvent="onTouchStart"
  open={open}
  onClickAway={() => open && setOpen(false)}
>
  <Drawer variant="persistent" {...props} />
</ClickAwayListener>
```

#### Temporary `Drawer`

```
<Drawer
  variant="temporary"
  open={open}
  onClose={(_, reason) =>
    reason === 'backdropClick' && setOpen(false)
  }
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: on the **Temporary Drawer** you can add an undefined condition to the reason like **(reason === 'backdropClick' || reason === undefined) && setOpen(false)** it useful when you use the *swipeableDrawer* compnent

Comment: `open` is an unsupported prop. Best to remove `open={open}`

Answer (score 4):

You can implement this yourself by adding a div in your `appFrame` which has an `onClick` that closes the drawer like this:

```
<div className={classes.appFrame}>
{this.state.open ? 
    <div style={{ position: "fixed", zIndex: 1, left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 }} 
        onClick={() => this.handleDrawerClose()} /> 
    : null
}
// rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks, @milo, but I was looking for Material-UI API solution. Though your answer is correct.

Comment: I use this solution instead, it works like a charm, where every other Material-UI props and ClickAwayListener couldn't work or didn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the "temporary" variant and retain state when opening and closing the drawer, you can pass the `keepMounted: true` prop to ModalProps of the drawer.

```
<Drawer 
  variant="temporary"
  ModalProps={{
    keepMounted: true,
  }}
>
 {children}
</Drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works with 1.0.0 version but this approach works for me noting that i am using the drawer from "material-ui/core @4.10"

```
<Drawer ... open={this.state.open} onClose={() => this.handleDrawerClose()}>
....
</Drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently found out about this neat useOnClickOutside hook => [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/23jk7wlw4y) and replaced all my with it. Much more elegant than adding an element to the dom and really easy to use with Mui now that you can pass a ref prop to any Material-ui component.

Comment: How would you handle it if you would always show the button? Like you would want to close the modal if the button is pressed but also if you click outside? Struggling to solve that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in **Drawer's open** attribute a **useState** and set to false in the onClose property:

`onClose={() => setOpen(false)}`

in this example, the useState name is ** open ** and ** setOpen **

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For searchers how have problem with closing the drawer when clicking outside, you can simply detect outside click in `onClose` prop. it takes a function and  runs it when you click outside of the drawer.

```
<Drawer open={state} onClose={() => setState(false)} >
</Drawer>
```