# Material-UI ClickAwayListener fires immediately

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So it appears that once I click to open my drawer, the click away listener fires simultaneously and immediately closes. This is because I click a menu icon to open it, but that menu icon is also outside of the drawer so it just immediately closes. Any ideas on how to work around this?

```
const ResponsiveMenu = ({setMenu, open, closeMenu}) => {
const classes = useStyles();
return (
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={closeMenu}>
    <Drawer open={open}>
        <IconButton className={classes.menuCloseIcon} onClick={setMenu}>
            <CloseIcon/>
        </IconButton>
        <img src="vectoredLogo.png" className={classes.menuLogo}/>
        <Divider/>
        <List>
            {['Home', 'About', 'Feedback', 'Login', 'Projects'].map((text, index) => {
                if (text === "About") {
                    return (
                        <ListItem className={classes.expansionHolder}>
                            <ExpansionPanel className={classes.expansionMenu}>
                                <ExpansionPanelSummary
                                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
                                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                                    className={classes.expansionLink}
                                >
                                    <Typography>About</Typography>
                                </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                                <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                                    <Typography>
                                        {['a', 'b', 'c'].map(text => {
                                            return (
                                                <ListItem button key={text} component="a"
                                                          href="https://www.google.com">
                                                    <ListItemText className={classes.menuLink} primary={text}/>
                                                </ListItem>
                                            );
                                        })}
                                    </Typography>
                                </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                            </ExpansionPanel>
                        </ListItem>
                    );
                } else {
                    return (
                        <ListItem button key={text} component="a" href="https://www.google.com">
                            <ListItemText className={classes.menuLink} primary={text}/>
                        </ListItem>
                    )
                }
            })}
        </List>
    </Drawer>
    </ClickAwayListener>
)
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close Persistent MUI Drawer on clicking outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060096/close-persistent-mui-drawer-on-clicking-outside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ClickAwayListener to close the Drawer, use modalProps:

```
  <Drawer ModalProps={{ onBackdropClick: closeMenu }}>
```